# understand complex function definition

Tags: c++, definition

i have a complex function definition written in c++. It is the first time i have come across such a complex function definition and i am having trouble understanding the meaning of it.

Here it is

```
t_group& t_group::operator=(const t_group &a)
{

}
```

specifically i need to know what

> operator=(const t_group &a)

mean ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: Why down-voted?  The question is properly formulated.
May be too easy for some arrogant expert ... but remember all of you where "child" somehow or sometime.

Comment: +1 It's not like operator overloading is a standard, or even necessary, feature of all computer languages. Also, operator overloading has a lot of semantics you have to learn sometime; it's not like functions where the parameters are pretty much arbitrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the breakdown:

```
t_group&
```

The function returns a reference to a `t_group`.

```
t_group::
```

The function is in the `t_group` namespace. Since `t_group` is the name of a `struct`, `union`, or `class`, it is a member of `t_group`.

```
operator=
```

The function is an *overload* of the `=` operator. Since it is a method, the object is the left-hand-side of the `=` operator.

```
(const t_group &a)
```

This is the parameter to the function: it's the right-hand-side of the `=` operator. This says the right-hand-side is a `const` reference to a `t_group`, which means the function will not alter the `t_group`.

Taken together, this is the *copy assignment* operation for the `t_group` class. It is invoked by code like:

```
t_group a, b;
b = a;
```

The latter line is equivalent to `b.operator=(a);`.

P.S. assignment operator functions typically end with `return *this;`. This is so you can chain the assignments (e.g. `a = b = c`) just like the regular `=` operator.